# Automation Peer of IScrollProvider is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, automation, scroll

I am trying to implement a way to move back the scroll bar of a datagrid back to a previous position following this sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109531/Controlling-and-Viewing-the-ScrollBar-Positions-of but this method always returns null making it impossible to create automation. Does any have an idea why this would always return null?

```
    public static IScrollProvider GetScrollProvider(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var p = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(grid)
            ?? FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(grid);
        return p.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll) as IScrollProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Do you remember if you figured out the problem here? I've ran into the same issue :/

Comment: I was never able to use the IScrollProvider... Instead I used a local varial and used the scrool to record on the datagrid!

Answer (score 1):

Ancient history, but at least current version seems to work liek charm in all cases.

```
//p.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll) as IScrollProvider;
{System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer}
    [System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer]: 
        {System.Windows.Automation.Peers.DataGridAutomationPeer}
    HorizontallyScrollable: true
    HorizontalScrollPercent: 0.0
    HorizontalViewSize: 81.44329896907216
    VerticallyScrollable: true
    VerticalScrollPercent: 29.062733871459486
    VerticalViewSize: 2.9625
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its a old post, but in case someone gets here with the same problem, (Like me), here is how i solved it:

For some reason, when you the the scrollbar of the DataGrid, if the user didn't scroll yet, it will inform that the maximum position is 0, even if it isn't. So i saved the maximum value before updating and restore it after:

First i create a class to save those values. It could be variables, but a class seemed more organized:

```
public class ScrollInfo
{
    public double HorizontalPosition;
    public double HorizontalMaximum;
    public double VerticalPosition;
    public double VerticalMaximum;
}
```

Before i update the ItemSource property i use this method to save Scroll info:

```
public static ScrollInfo GetScrollInfo(this DataGrid grid)
{
    ScrollInfo oInfo = new ScrollInfo();

    ScrollBar sbHorizontal = grid.GetScrollbar(ScrollMode.Horizontal);
    oInfo.HorizontalMaximum = sbHorizontal.Maximum;
    oInfo.HorizontalPosition = sbHorizontal.Value;

    ScrollBar sbVertical = grid.GetScrollbar(ScrollMode.Vertical);
    oInfo.VerticalMaximum = sbVertical.Maximum;
    oInfo.VerticalPosition = sbVertical.Value;

    return oInfo;
}
```

And then i call this method to set this info back to the grid after the update:

```
public static void SetScrollPosition(this DataGrid grid, ScrollInfo info)
{
    if (info.HorizontalPosition > 0)
    {
        ScrollBar sbHorizontal = grid.GetScrollbar(ScrollMode.Horizontal);
        sbHorizontal.Maximum = info.HorizontalMaximum;
        grid.Scroll(ScrollMode.Horizontal, info.HorizontalPosition);
    }

    if (info.VerticalPosition > 0)
    {
        ScrollBar sbVertical = grid.GetScrollbar(ScrollMode.Vertical);
        sbVertical.Maximum = info.VerticalMaximum;            
        grid.Scroll(ScrollMode.Vertical, info.VerticalPosition);
    }
}
```

I even create a UpdateItemSource method to make things easier:

```
public static void UpdateItemSource(this DataGrid grid, IEnumerable itemSource)
{
    ScrollInfo oInfo = grid.GetScrollInfo();
    grid.ItemsSource = itemSource;
    grid.SetScrollPosition(oInfo);
}
```

Other methods I use, wich i guess i take from the same post the user who post the question did:

```
public static void Scroll(this DataGrid grid, ScrollMode mode, double position)
{
    // Get the scrollbar and convert the position to percent.
    var scrollBar = grid.GetScrollbar(mode);
    double positionPct = ((position / scrollBar.Maximum) * 100);

    // Scroll to a specfic percentage of the scrollbar.
    grid.ScrollToPercent(mode, positionPct);
}

public static void ScrollToPercent(this DataGrid grid, ScrollMode mode, double percent)
{
    // Fix the percentage.
    if (percent < 0)
        percent = 0;
    else if (percent > 100)
        percent = 100;

    // Get the scroll provider.
    var scrollProvider = GetScrollProvider(grid);

    // Scroll.
    switch (mode)
    {
        case ScrollMode.Vertical:                        
            scrollProvider.SetScrollPercent( System.Windows.Automation.ScrollPatternIdentifiers.NoScroll, percent);
            break;
        case ScrollMode.Horizontal:
            scrollProvider.SetScrollPercent(percent, System.Windows.Automation.ScrollPatternIdentifiers.NoScroll);
            break;
    }
}
```